# How to disable "Site Content" in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, css

How can I disable Site content from this place:

[image]

I want to be disable for non-admin users. I am not using Seattle.masterpage but instead I am using bootrap.masterpage. This means that i DO NOT HAVE THIS ID: `ID="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents"` 
how can I hide sitecontents from "gear icon" menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would only work as long as you have the English version going on

li[text="Site contents"]{display:none;}

Comment: Oh but that will hide it for everybody, not just non-admins.

Comment: i can handle in different way for non-admin users thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look for "PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" content-place holder in your custom master page and comment out the DIV tag as shown in the below link.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5d30118a-8be7-4ed7-9f0d-b40ecf1054fd/a-menu-item-called-site-contents-on-the-left-site-menu-of-my-site?forum=sharepointgeneral